# Memory leak when using readline in joined or detached thread

Tags: c

For the past 2 hours or so, I have been trying to figure out why the following code throws a "possibly lost" memory leak:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

void *my_read(void* arg) {
    char* buf;
    if ((buf = readline(">> ")) != NULL) {
        printf("Test\n");
        if (strlen(buf) > 0) {
            add_history(buf);
        }
        free(buf);
    }
  
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    rl_catch_signals = 0;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, my_read, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And I have also tried using `detach` instead of `join`, but the result is the same, which is:

```
==1498903== 272 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 31 of 78
==1498903==    at 0x4849C0F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1328)
==1498903==    by 0x4012662: allocate_dtv (in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
==1498903==    by 0x401309D: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
==1498903==    by 0x497FAA4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.34 (in /lib64/libc.so.6)
==1498903==    by 0x10927B: main (in /home/user/readline)
```

I have also tried just straight up allocating memory and freeing it in a loop, which shows the same result.

**EDIT:** Picked the `read` -> `my_read` fix from Ajay, but the main issue still remains.

Comment: Are you sure your function runs to completion? I am seeing a Segfault in the thread that exits the application and never calls `pthread_join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that you have defined a function named `read`. Readline internally calls the `read` function to read from `stdin`. This ends up recursively calling your read function leading to a stackoverflow and crashing your program. The crashed program doesn't free memory for the `pthread_t` state which should be done when you call `pthread_join`. This is the main reason valgrind complains.

A simple fix is to `read` --> `my_read`.

With the proposed fix the output of `valgrind --leak-check=full` on my end is -

```
==27167== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27167== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27167== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27167== Command: ./test
==27167==
>> hello
Test
==27167==
==27167== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27167==     in use at exit: 134,297 bytes in 195 blocks
==27167==   total heap usage: 316 allocs, 121 frees, 155,633 bytes allocated
==27167==
==27167== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27167==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27167==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27167==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27167==    still reachable: 134,297 bytes in 195 blocks
==27167==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27167== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==27167== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==27167==
==27167== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27167== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: While the fix to my_read is correct it does not fix the valgrind complaint at all.

Comment: I just ran the fixed version and I see `==27167== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27167==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27167==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27167==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27167==    still reachable: 134,297 bytes in 195 blocks
==27167==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks` on my end

Comment: Also please don't edit the question to apply fixes that have been proposed in answers. This makes it incredibly hard for future readers to understand the relevance between the questions and the answers. Please leave your question as it is and bring up follow ups in the comments. If the followup is significant, post another question.

Comment: I just created a new file with the code in the question to be sure i cant mix it up. I still see 272bytes possibly lost on my end.

Now im actually wondering if this may be host issue as in system and not the actual code.

Comment: I just had the code tested on another of my machines. Valgrind does not report issue there. Seems to be a system issue. (System: Gentoo Linux)

Comment: Maybe you can get rid of all the `readline` related stuff and just call `pthread_exit` from your thread. If that still shows a memory leak (despite calling pthread join), the problem might be elsewhere